# Returns the distanceTo() method, for calculating the distance between two locations, the metres from the linear distance?

Tags: android, locationmanager

I want to know if the method `distanceTo()` returns the metres from the linear distance or the real distance which you have to drive from location A to location B.

My thought is that it is the linear distance, but I don't know it exactly.

Does it anybody know exactly?

Comment: It's absolutely linear distance.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29):

> *Returns the approximate distance in meters between this location and the given location. Distance is defined using the WGS84 ellipsoid.*

So it is the distance over the surface of the ellipsoid.

Reading the source code for `Location.java`, as of API 18 the `distanceTo` method calls the private method `computeDistanceAndBearing`. At the beggining of this method you can find this comment:

```
// Based on http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf
// using the "Inverse Formula" (section 4)
```

It is an iterative method (n=20). You can check that document to see the formula they are using.

Answer (score 0):

Distances provided by all methods e.g. google maps, Location class etc. from point A to point B consists of a number of smaller straight lines. A poly line.
so from A to B, there could be say, A,D,E,F,B. In such case A-D will be a linear straight line - a liner distance. D-E again is a linear distance.

When you add up all the linear distances, you get the actual driving distance from A to B.